# LaTeX jpg display

Tags: latex

I 'm new to LaTeX and still learning. So I have this issue with jpg images. The code is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{images.jpg}
        \caption{A boat.}
        \label{fig:boat1}
    \end{figure}
    Figure \ref{fig:boat1} shows a boat.
\end{document}
```

The result is a pdf file with the caption and the reference, but without the picture. Any solutions? Thanks.

Comment: This piece of code should work if `images.jpg` is in the same directory as the `.tex` file that you compile.

Comment: It is I believe, since it compiles without error, and png images in the same folder display correctly.

Comment: FWIW, it works for me. Is there anything in the log file that might explain this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile your document with pdflatex. The regular tex compiler doesn;t work with .jpg images.